# When does Kendo context menu get anchored?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, contextmenu, kendo-contextmenu

When does Kendo context menu get anchored?  My problem is the context menu opens in slightly the wrong spot.  I have the `alignToAnchor` set to `true`.  Everything works except when I am adding the first item in the grid.  Then the context menu is slightly off.  The problem is likely because I have custom row templates and I have to add a custom header as well.  The custom header throws it off.  This behavior isn't just on the first time that the user right-clicks on the row.  It is always when the user right-clicks on the row.  And then with a refresh on the page, a right-click on that record puts the contextMenu in the right place.

Here are a couple of things that I've tried:

1) Destroying the contextMenu and reinitializing after the first record is created.

2) Adding a class to all the rows `noContextMenu`.  Change the filter on the contextMenu to `tr:not(.noContextMenu)` and then adding a line to the end of the `dataBound: $(".noContextMenu").removeClass("noContextMenu");`  (So then, the `noContextMenu` class is only in effect during popup editing.)

3) Digging into the contextMenu object and overwriting the target variable.

Answer (score 0):

See if that workaround will work for you:

```
$("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
    open: function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          e.sender.element.parent().css('top', e.event.pageY).css('left', e.event.pageX);
      });
    }
    ...
});
```